# English as a second language and more

Tags: discussion

1. Are people who do not speak english fluently not allowed here on SE-physics? (Since they may not be able to format properly or choose the clearest words).  Usually i can understand what someone is talking about by context but ive seen complaints and closures.
2. What can we do if we are being harassed by another user(s)?

Ive come to notice some elitists and trolls that post comments not related to the physics question or ridicule others for asking a question they find elementary or uneccesarry.

How can we combat these behaviors?

Comment: Why would this question get downvoted?  Did i do something wrong?

Comment: I don't know, I think it's a decent question.

Comment: Voting on meta can express a disagreement with a position stated by the post, as well as a judgement that there is something wrong with the post. I image that someone could feel that @user122066 is misrepresnting what's been going on.

Comment: Comments deleted. Basic hint: telling another user to go away is a violation of the "Be nice." policy.

Comment: More comments deleted. Now would be a very good time to *let it go.*

Comment: @user122066: What does the second question have to do with the first? They seem like two unrelated concepts as currently stated, though additional context may help explain why they're relevant.

Comment: A good question. Ask me, I have read four languages in my life and was not good in any of them. I faced problems in vocabulary, the use of tenses,  formatting etc. Language has always been an issue, an example of this would be countries where english is official language just because of language diversity and pride in each language. As suggested by @Constantine I think English needs to be adjusted in culture just because of its almost universal usage and big development.

Comment: Hello @Sikander   I agree there should be a more methodological contact with English. But, I also think there should be an effort of "creating" terminology for a science in every language as an inner discipline that will allow an inner state development of the particular scientific field, here physics. Of course this is pure theory or fantasy in our time( at least in my country) but I can't help thinking that such a systematic method would benefit science all around the globe- there would be more internal interactions in each country...

Comment: and then English would be the code of communicating, something necessary today as it always was( in ancient there where Greek or Latin). An example of the more methodological contact will be of course a more systematic exposure in pre- graduate school with English written papers- although I am sure this already is a fact in some countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the language, I don't think there is a formal solution. In the end, if physics becomes a main discipline for you, you will be in need of learning better English so you can read papers and articles. On the trolling staff, just don't pay attention on the way a comment or a message is being phrased. Rather, consider if there is anything from that comment that might help you evolve. If it is completely irrelevant, ignore it.

Comment: To make a physics-irrelevant comment question: what *is* that thingie on your avatar with the most wonderful amazing blue in it? Is it an enamelling on copper or something like that?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance  Hello. An example will be someone asking about the inflation period( not a philosophical question, something technical like the BICEP2 experiment) and someone commenting that the whole story about inflation is sci-fi and that we should be waiting around another 50 years or so before asking questions that cannot be confirmed experimentally at the moment. I do not disagree with the argument that states modern cosmology as a pure theroretical discipline at many areas, but such a comment is irrelevant with the question as long as physicists do cosmo. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

Physics Stack Exchange runs in English, but that is not to exclude people for whom English is not a native tongue. When you see what appears to be someone struggling with the language you can (a) ask them if your re-phrasing is what they mean, or if you are fairly confident (b) simple edit (assuming you have that privilege) and make a comment to the effect that you have tried to improve the working and was that correct.

There are two aspirations at work here:

- The users of Physics should be trying to make the question as good as they can.
- The original poster should take the time to make their question as clear as possible, and actively interact with and support users who are trying to help improve the question.

These questions *are* more likely to get closed, but if they can be cleaned up they should be fairly easy to get re-opened as well.